# Android: what is the id of startForeground(id,notification) in Service Class

Tags: android, service, notifications

What is the id parameter in `startForground` method in Service class.I found that answer by googling for single Notification.How do the guy find the id ? any list or reference for this.What if i want to show multiple notification like facebook. How do i define the id then ?

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
startForeground(1337, notification);
```

Comment: It can be any integer and if the number of notifications is fixed, its always nice to store them in a `static final int` variable

Comment: do i have any advantage by storing this variable ? like destroying the specific notification  by id ?

Comment: When you store it, you don't have to remember it, simply changing at a single place will make it changing everywhere. Hence, less chances of errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple notification_id needs to be changeable.

Just create random number for notification_id.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
or
        int m = System.currentTimeMillis()%10000;
```

and replace this line to add parameter for notification id as to generate random number

```
    startForeground(m, notification);
```

Comment: yes the next one with currentTime will always be unique

Comment: @GodslaveAsad Even after modular (`%`) operation?

Comment: SecureRandom() reduces conflicts

Comment: Second one when called more times immediately gives same number !!! You are asking for some trouble in some future with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Better create unique number like this for notification id or just define a constant if thats viable option:

```
fun Int.Companion.uniue(length: Int): Int {
    val string = "${nanoTime()}"
    val subString = string.substring(string.length - length, string.length - length + length)
    return subString.toInt()
}

@Test
fun uniue() {
    val value1 = Int.uniue(9)
    val value2 = Int.uniue(9)
    val value3 = Int.uniue(9)
    val value4 = Int.uniue(9)
    assertNotEquals(value1, value2)
    assertNotEquals(value2, value3)
    assertNotEquals(value3, value4)
    assertEquals(9, value1.toString().length)
    assertEquals(9, value2.toString().length)
    assertEquals(9, value3.toString().length)
    assertEquals(9, value4.toString().length)
}
```

enjoy